# List comprehension slower when set is declared inside

Tags: python, performance, set, list-comprehension

I tested two snippets of code and found out that declaring a set ahead of using it in a list comprehension was **much** faster than declaring it inside the list comprehension. Why does this happen? (Using python 3.9.13)

```
import time

# Setup
a = [x for x in range(10000)]
b = [x for x in range(8000)]

t = time.time()
b = set(b)
[x for x in a if x in b]
print(time.time() - t)
# 0.0010492801666259766


t = time.time()
[x for x in a if x in set(b)]
print(time.time() - t)
# 1.0515294075012207
```

I didn't expect there to be orders of magnitude of a difference...

Comment: Because in the latter case `set(b)` is being re-evaluated on every iteration.

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect that! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just to clarify, would this apply to any kind of expression that replaces `set(b)`?

Comment: Yes. Because it's a function call. If you did `... if check(x)`, you'd expect that to get called every time, right?

Comment: I guess I expected it to be called only once and cached, but it makes total sense it would get called every iteration. Thanks!

Comment: Just as an aside (as you seem to be concerned with performance)... *a=list(range(10000))* is significantly faster than the list comprehension you're using

Comment: @Cobra I imagine this was just an example (`out = list(range(8001, 10000))` is even faster) ;)

Comment: @Cobra Didn't know that, thanks for letting me know! (And indeed, it was just something I cooked up as an example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `set([iterable])` function returns object of type `set` and inside the list comprehension you are repeating the execution of the function in each iteration, while in first case you only reference its result to `b` variable and execute the list comprehension on the referenced object.